# How to print array element line by line inside a textarea by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dataset inside a array and I checked which data satisfy the given date range and then I need to print that data set inside textarea line by line.

My code:

```
document.write('<div id="div1">'); 
    document.write('<b>Start date and time : </b><input type="date" id="start_date"/>  <input type="time" id="start_time"/></br></br>');
    document.write('<b>End date and time    : </b><input type="date" id="end_date"/>  <input type="time" id="end_time"/></br></br>');
    document.write('<button id="Load_button"  > Load</button>'); 
document.write('</div>'); 



document.write('<form action="player.html" id="frm1" method="get">');
    document.write('<textarea id="area" style="border: 1px; width: 100%; height=50% ">blah blah blah....</textarea>');
    document.write('<input type="submit" value="Filter">');
document.write('</form>');

document.getElementById('Load_button').addEventListener('click', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
   var date1 = Date.parse(document.getElementById('start_date').value);
   var time1 = (document.getElementById('start_time').value);
   var date2 = Date.parse(document.getElementById('end_date').value);
   var time2 = document.getElementById('end_time').value;

   var new_arr = [];
   var date_finder =/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/;
   var time_finder =/\d\d:\d\d/ ;   
   document.getElementById('area').value = "" ;

   for(var i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){
        var date = Date.parse(date_finder.exec(arr[i]));
        var time = time_finder.exec(arr[i]);

        if (date <= date2 && date >= date1) {
            new_arr[i] = arr[i];
        }

    document.getElementById('area').value = document.getElementById('area').value +  document.write('<input type="checkbox" name="lines" value=" ' + i+' ">' + new_arr[i]+ '<br />');   
    }

});
```

Output window:
[image]

How to fix this using html and javaScript?I just can't understand what is the reason for print as "undefined" and how to print the result set line by line inside the textarea.  Please give me a help.
-Thank you-

Comment: Don't post *pictures* of your code here. Post the code itself.